# keep getting these errors while upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, boot, updates

I updated from 14.04 to 16.04 but these files could not get installed

```
linux-firmware
linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-generic
initramfs-tools
```

I got a warning that system may be unstable

I tried to install them seprately using :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but keep getting this:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

please help

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: still getting this                                                                                                               Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
 initramfs-tools

Comment: run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: got this     Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools